# Recursive method in a Doubly linked list

Tags: java, recursion, methods, data-structures, linked-list

I need to develop a recursive method **(can't use while, do ... while and for)**  in a doubly linked list that returns the ith element of the list if **i** is >= 0 and if **i** is smaller than the value of the list. Otherwise returns **null**. Any help would be much appreciated.
Also here's my iterative method:

```
public String get(int i) {
    if(i<0 || i>=lenght) {
        return null;
    }
    Node t = head;
    for(int c = 0; c != i; c++) {
       t = t.next;
    }
    return t.element;
}
```

Comment: Any iterative method can also be written recursively, but what aspect are you having a problem with? Have you written a recursive method which doesn't work?

Comment: Here's a description of the recursive algorithm you need to implement: if i is 1 then return the current element otherwise get the element at position i-1 after the current element

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
public String get(int i) {
    if(i<0 || i>=lenght) return null;
    return iter(head, i)
}


public String iter(Node t,int i){
    if(t == null) return null;
    if(i == 0) return t.elemnt;
    return iter(t.next, i - 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String get(Node current, int currentIndex, int targetIndex) {
    // first check the exit condition of the method
    if(currentIndex <0 || currentIndex >= length || current == null) {
            return null;
    }
    // check the second exit contidion
    if (currentIndex == targetIndex)
    {
        return current.element;
    }
    // go forward by increasing the index
    return get(current.next, currentIndex + 1, targetIndex);
}
```